# put every alternate row in a column using some Unix commands

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a file with foll format:

```
key1
123
key2
345
```

I want to get it as:

```
key1 123
key2 345
```

I am trying a mix of seds , grep etc but not quite getting what I want. Any suggestions . 
I think deleteing "\n" on every odd row would also do the trick but can get that to work .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might work for you:

```
echo -e "key1\n123\nkey2\n456" | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

Comment: The `N` command appends a newline, then the next line to the current line. The `s/\n/ /` replaces the newline (`\n`) with a space.

Answer (score 6):

This is a job for [paste](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste)

```
paste -d " " - - < filename
```