# How to convert xml file in to a property file using unix shell script

Tags: xml, shell, unix

I have an xml file source.xml. I want to create an property file with key-value pairs from this xml file info.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<persons>
  <person>
    <name>John</name>
    <family-name>Smith</family-name>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Morka</name>
    <family-name>Ismincius</family-name>
  </person>
</persons>
```

Property file should look like

```
"John" = "Smith";
"Morka" = "Ismincius";
```

Anyone did similar kind of conversion using Unix Shell Script please suggest..

Can it be done simply using `grep and sed command`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searched a lot and finally able to create properties file from xml using simple `grep and sed` unix commands.

Couple of links good enough to refer :

[How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

[put every alternate row in a column using some Unix commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442459/put-every-alternate-row-in-a-column-using-some-unix-commands)

The script worked :

```
grep -e "<name>" -e "<family-name>" source.xml  | 
sed -e 's/<name>/"/' -e 's/<\/name>/"/' | 
sed -e 's/<family-name>/"/' -e 's/<\/family-name>/";/' |
sed 's/ //g' |
sed 'N;s/\n/ = /' > my.properties
```

Anyone having any other way to do the same using simple unix commands please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

this may help?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//person">
"<xsl:value-of select="name"/>" = "<xsl:value-of select="family-name"/>"
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

save it as `x.xslt`
and do

```
xsltproc x.xslt file.xml
```

Comment: I have tried all processes like xsltproc, saxon and eclipse plugin etc. But requirement is to perform this using Shell script. Do u have any idea?